# Global minimum on $\cos x+\cos kx$; $k$ irrational

Tags: trigonometry, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, mathematica

I'm trying to find the global minimum on $$\cos x+\cos kx$$ with $k$ irrational.

The fact that the function oscillates fairly quickly makes it pretty unreasonable to compute the derivative and set it equal to zero (I haven't been able to solve $-\sin x-\sin kx=0$ analytically or numerically anyways), and the local minimums are reasonably close making it hard to tell from the graph.

I tried using Mathematica's NDSolve function to no avail, and every time I broaden the range on FindMinimum I get a different result!

Edit: If there is no global minimum, is there a way to generate the local minima?

Any suggestions about numerically, graphically or analytically solving this problem would be welcome!

Comment: Abandon all hope. There is no global minimum. There are local minima arbitrarily close to -2. Oh wait, and there is a global maximum at $x=0$; will that do?

Comment: Nuts. Is there a way to prove there's no global minimum?

Comment: Yeah, it goes along the lines _"fractional part of $kn$ are dense in (0,1), hence there will be points where $x$ and $kx$ are both arbitrarily close to some integer multiples of $\pi$, hence..."_

Comment: If $\cos x + \cos k x = -2$ then both $x = \frac{\pi}{2} + \pi n, kx = \frac{\pi}{2} + \pi m, n,m \in \mathbb Z$ which immediately leads to $k \in \mathbb Q$.

Comment: I remember once when I had to graph $y=sin(sqrt(2)*x)+sin(sqrt(3)*x)+sin(sqrt(5)*x)$